# How to configure name based virtual hosts on Apache 2.4 in Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, subdomain

I'm new to both Linux and apache.

I have a website hosted on my computer using apache. Assume the domain is `www.myweb.com`. Now I want to make 3 subdomains `a.myweb.com` and `b.myweb.com`.

My first question is that can i do this by using virtual hosts. Cause all the virtual hosts examples I can find use different domains so I'm not sure if it also applies to subdomain.

My second question is based on that virtual hosts works for subdomain. In my `httpd.conf` file, the value of `DocumentRoot` is`/srv/http`. Under `/srv/http`, I created 3 folders, `default`, `a` and `b`. And here is my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost myIP:80>
    ServerAdmin a@b.c 
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/default/public"
    ServerName www.myweb.com
    ServerAlias myweb.com
    ErrorLog "/srv/http/default/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/srv/http/default/logs/access.log" combined
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost myIP:80>
    ServerAdmin a@b.c 
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/a/public"
    ServerName a.myweb.com
    ErrorLog "/srv/http/a/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog  "/srv/http/a/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost myIP:80>
    ServerAdmin a@b.c 
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/b/public"
    ServerName b.myweb.com
    ErrorLog "/srv/http/b/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog  "/srv/http/b/logs/access.log" combined   
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the problem is, when I type `www.myweb.com`, `myweb.com`, `a.myweb.com` or `b.myweb.com` in my browser, I'm always taken to `DocumentRoot`, which is `/srv/http`. So did I do something wrong or subdomain can't work this way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you can use virtualhost sections in `httpd.conf` for subdomains; I do that. Did you restart Apache, e.g., with `apachectl restart`, after editing `httpd.conf` to match what you show in your posting?

Comment: All my virtual hosts settings are in httpd-vhosts.conf, should I put them in httpd.conf instead? I restart apache every time I change the config files.

Comment: no, you should be able to use `httpd-vhosts.conf` if you have `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `httpd.conf` with no "#" sign at the beginning of the line to comment it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you use `<VirtualHost myIP:80>` at the start of your virtualhost sections. I use `<VirtualHost *:80>` for all of my named-based virtual hosts - see [How To Setup Apache Virtual Host Configuration (With Examples)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/) for the difference between configuring a server for name-based virutal hosts versus IP-based virtual hosts. If the server has multiple IP addresses and you want the sites to respond on different IP addresses, I'd think you would put in an IP address, but if all sites should be accessible using any IP address the server is listening on then try the "*", instead of the IP address in the virtualhost sections, to see if that makes a difference. Otherwise, your configuration looks similar to my own. You could also try `httpd -S` to check the VirtualHost configuration synatax as suggested in that article to see if anything Apache reports by that check looks amiss.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full paths in the 'Directory' directive as required in the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory). With your configuration you actually configuring access to your 'DocumentRoot' path configured in httpd.conf from the respective host name.

The 'Directory' configuration section for your default website (www) may look like the following:

```
<Directory /srv/http/default/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also to note, that default access for Directory "/" is to permit all access, which means that Apache httpd will serve any file mapped from an URL. So as suggested in the documentation you may want to change it to something more restricted in your httpd.conf.

```
<Directory "/">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```